# Neumann-Neumann boundary intersection

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, multigrid, elliptic-pde

[image]
I am trying to solve a *Vertex Centered*, *Finite Difference*, *Poisson* equation $-\nabla^{2}u=f$ with *Dirichlet* boundaries on the left and bottom and *Neumann* boundaries on the top and right using *Geometric Multigrid*. An illustration is shown in 2-D (apologies for the hand drawn figure). **Crosses** indicate unknowns, **red squares** indicate ghost points for Neumann boundary, **D** indicates Dirichlet, **9-pt** stencil is shown in green lines.  It is given that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ at Neumann boundaries.

1. If I use a **9-pt** stencil in 2-D to approximate variable $u$ at various mesh points, what will be the value of the point at the `Green questions mark`?
2. Should I be using a **5-pt** stencil at the Neumann-Neumann boundary intersection?
3. Will using a 5-pt stencil at the corner point not deteriorate the `convergence rate` in Multigrid?
4. If I use the 9-pt stencil at the top-left boundary, are we not taking a Dirichlet point which is outside the physical domain ?

Comment: I dont have an answer but curious to know the answer. How will 5-pt stencil help, since the neumann condition does not make sense at a corner. If (nx,ny) is the top-right corner point, how do you get the ghost value at (nx+1,ny) and (nx,ny+1) ?

Comment: @PraveenChandrashekar: Its given that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$, so we can use it to find u(nx+1,ny) and u(nx,ny+1). For example, using central difference : $\frac{u(nx,ny+1) - u(nx,ny-1)}{2h}=0$, hence $u(nx,ny+1) = u(nx,ny-1)$. Simiarly we can find u(nx+1,ny). Thus, 5-pt stencil can be applied.

Comment: ok, so you take $u_x=0$ and $u_y=0$ at the top-right corner. Then you could do $u(nx+1,ny+1)=u(nx-1,ny-1)$ to get the corner ghost value ???

Comment: @PraveenChandrashekar: How exactly do you derive this ?

Comment: If you take $u_x=u_y=0$ then every directional derivative is zero. Use this along the line joining $(nx-1,ny-1)$ to $(nx+1,ny+1)$.

Comment: @PraveenChandrashekar: Sounds logical. Its like the velocity of a car has 0 x and y component, so it doesn't have a velocity in the X-Y plane. But I still have my doubts though...